# Problem regarding functions and sequences

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, solution-verification

[image]

There is just so much going on in this question that I feel kind of lost.
How should I connect all the information into something that will help me? I've tried opening up the definition of limit of f(x), using continuity, using differentiability to no vail.. I'm having a hard time grasping the combination of functions and sequences into one problem..

Comment: Please use mathjax rather than images. This [guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's summarize the most important points:

1. $f:[a,b]\to[a,b]$ is differentiable and $f(\alpha)=\alpha$
2. $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $[a,b]$ with $f(x_{n})=x_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.
3. Assume the derivative of $f$ is bounded less than one: $|f'(x)|\leq q<1$.
4. Show that $x_n$ converges to $\alpha$.

from the hint, we need to compare $|x_{n+1}-\alpha|$ and $|x_n-\alpha|$. From points (1) and (2), we have $|x_{n+1}-\alpha|=|f(x_n)-f(\alpha)|$. By the Mean Value Theorem (which I am guessing is Lagrange's theorem), we have if $$\left|\frac{f(x_n)-f(\alpha)}{x_n-\alpha}\right|>q,$$ then there must be a point $y$ between $\alpha$ and $x_n$ such that $|f'(y)|>q$, but this contradicts point (3). Therefore, $$|x_{n+1}-\alpha|=|f(x_n)-f(\alpha)|<q|x_n-\alpha|.$$ We can apply this fact inductively to see that $|x_n-\alpha|<q^n|x_1-\alpha|.$ Thus, since $q<1$, $|x_n-\alpha|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, so $x_n$ converges to $\alpha$.

Comment: Good guess.  I've seen it called "Lagrange's mean value theorem," to distinguish it from [Cauchy's mean value theorem](https://www.math24.net/cauchys-mean-value-theorem)